# Default value for drop down list in yii

Tags: php, yii, drop-down-menu

I have a static dropDownList which is simply a list of years. i want the default value to be the current year(im using the date() in php). How do i do this in yii?

heres my dropDownList code:

```
<?php echo $form->dropDownList($model,'YEAR',
          array ('1990' => ... => '2020')
          );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible by setting default value to the $model.

```
<?php
    // see http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php#refsect1-function.date-parameters
    // for more details about the parameter of date() function.
    $model->YEAR= date('Y');
    // see https://github.com/yiisoft/yii/blob/1.1.15/framework/web/helpers/CHtml.php#L1799
    // to know how Yii detect selected value.
    echo $form->dropDownList(
        $model,
        'YEAR',
        array (
            '1990'  => ...,
            ...
            '2020'  => ...
        )
    );
?>
```

about date() see [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php#refsect1-function.date-parameters) , and about dropDownList() see [here](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii/blob/1.1.15/framework/web/helpers/CHtml.php#L1799).